structure /sys/fs/cgroup/memory.stat
What is the structure of  linux memory via /sys/fs/cgroup/memory.stat?
what is the anon memory?
What is the file memory?

how to get the full used memory via /sys/fs?

Many of the kernel data structures are documented on-line.  A search in goo-gle returned this page as the third result:  https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/memory.html
There are four places "memory.stat" appears in the page.  The 3rd and 4th ones seem to have the most details about the lines/fields in the file.

You directed him to the docs of cgroups v1, but seems he's using v2. This page has the full explanation.

@aviro I'd think someone called Irina would probably prefer to be called a she ;)
